# Losing Data when switching to another view controller Xcode Swift

Tags: swift, database, xcode, struct, uitabbarcontroller

I'm having trouble figuring out exactly what's going on. Basically, I'm opening my first view controller which takes a users info from firebase. i.e. the name and uid. I'm sending data by `didSet()` in my second view controller (this is sent before the second view controller is opened). The data does get sent because I've tested it by using `print()`. However, when I navigate to my second view controller (using a tab controller and navigation controller, the data is no longer there when I navigate to my second view controller.

```
import Foundation
struct User {
    let uid: String
    let name: String
    init(uid: String, dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.uid = uid
        self.name = dictionary["uname"] as? String ?? ""
    }
}
```

Then in my first controller I use:

```
guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
    print("Could not init User at start")
    return }
Database.database().fetchUser(withUID: uid) { (user) in
secondController.user = user
}
```

..
In my secondView controller I have:

```
  var user: User? {
        didSet {
        printUser()

        }
    }

printUser(){
let uid = user?.uid
print(uid)
}
```

This is how I know the data is sent.

However, when I Navigate to the second viewcontroller by a tab bar controller and navigation controller, the data is not there. i.e I have `printUser()` in view did load, but it comes up as an error because user?.uid is nil.

I'm navigating viewControllers through storyboard.

[image]

Comment: please add the code how you are navigating to the second viewcontroller

Comment: Im using storyboard to navigate view controllers. Ive edited my question. cheers

Comment: Can't see the code you call `NotificationCenter.default.post(name: loadedUser, object: nil)`

`addObserver` won't trigger if you don't call `post`

Comment: edited, Im using didSet(). Am I creating a new instance when I use didSet from my first controller from the instance i create when i navigate through storyboard?

Comment: where did you used the navigation controller? are you changing the tab only? and how did you create secondController in the first view controller, i think it is creating different instance for second view controller in code, and when the viewcontroller is changed in the storyboard it is different instance

Comment: my understanding is that I create my second viewcontroller by using `Database.database().fetchUser(withUID: uid) { (user) in
secondController.user = user`, this then changes the initial value of `user`, which then runs my didSet() function that prints a value from the second viewcontroller, while the user/viewer is still on the first view controller